# Polynomial Pigeon hole principle problem

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

Find all triples of positive integers a<b<c for which
1/a +1/b + 1/c = 1 holds.

How should I proceed?
I am self learning combinatorics and I have to solve it using pigeon hole principle. This is the first exercise question from the book ' A walk through combinatorics'.

Comment: Start by spotting why $a \le 3$

Comment: @Henry I thought about it. Still can’t figure it out. Can you give some more hint? Is it some popular series? I haven’t been taught that in my school

Comment: $\frac 13 + \frac 13 + \frac13  = 1,$ but it won't do.

Comment: If $a>3$ then $b>3$ and $c>3$ so  $\frac1a + \frac1b+\frac1c< 1$ so that does not work.  If $a=3$ then $\frac1b + \frac1c=\frac23$ so $b \cdots $ and so ....    If $a=2$ then $\frac1b+\frac1c=\frac12$ so $b \cdots $ and so ....  If $a=1$ then $\frac1b+\frac1c=0$ and so ....

Comment: @Henry I got it. Thank you.